# MaxReceivedMessageSize property not registering

Tags: web-config

I am receiving the following error when running my site:

```
 System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (50000000) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

So I increased this property in my client and server web.config files.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000"></binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

As you see I increased it to "250000000". However, when running I still get the exact same message saying that the message size is only "50000000". Is there something else I am missing to change the size of the maxReceivedMessageSize property?

Comment: I don't think you're targeting the correct binding. I'd be expecting the binding to be mentioned by name.

Comment: Yep. You are exactly right. I just found the server binding name I am supposed to be referencing. Kudos. If you change that to an answer I will mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not targeting the correct binding. You should be mentioning it by name.

Example of this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize = "1000000">
    <security mode="None" />
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Details [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.100).aspx)